# VBA Macro Freezes after executing this code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit of code that runs but once it has ran and populated columns J & K, the code just freezes and doesn't finish off the rest of the macro below it, any help much appreciated!

```
Range("K1").Value = "Order Qty"
Range("K1").Font.Bold = True

Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow as Long
lastRow = Range("J2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Range("J" & i + 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$K:$K, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A))+1, """"), ROW(A" & i & "))),"""")"
    Range("K" & i + 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$K:$K, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D))+1, """"), ROW(A" & i & "))),"""")"
Next i
```

*** EDIT to show my complete code *** It takes just 2 seconds to run this code and then excel freezes until I "Kill it", the mouse shows the "whirling circle" as if it is doing something but I have left it running for 20 minutes and it has still been froze

```
Sub PrintDespatches()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim FileName As String, path As String
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

path = "Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Despatches\*.csv"

FileName = Dir(path, vbNormal)
Do Until FileName = ""
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set mynetwork = CreateObject("WScript.network")
mynetwork.setdefaultprinter "\\DOFFUKFS01\Olivetti MF280 PS"     'write your printers name here
Workbooks.Open Left(path, Len(path) - 5) & FileName
Range("H:H").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Range("K1").Value = "Order Qty"
Range("K1").Font.Bold = True

Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("J2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Range("J" & i + 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$K:$K, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A))+1, """"), ROW(A" & i & "))),"""")"
    Range("K" & i + 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$K:$K, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D))+1, """"), ROW(A" & i & "))),"""")"
Next i

Range("L1").Value = "Pick Qty"
Range("L1").Font.Bold = True
Range("L2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J2="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J2))"
Range("L3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J3="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J3))"
Range("L4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J4="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J4))"
Range("L5").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J5="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J5))"
Range("L6").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J6="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J6))"
Range("L7").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J7="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J7))"
Range("L8").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J8="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J8))"
Range("L9").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J9="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J9))"
Range("L10").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J10="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J10))"
Range("L11").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J11="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J11))"
Range("L12").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J12="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J12))"
Range("L13").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J13="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J13))"
Range("L14").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J14="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J14))"
Range("L15").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J15="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J15))"
Range("L16").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J16="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J16))"
Range("L17").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J17="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J17))"
Range("L18").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J18="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J18))"
Range("L19").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J19="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J19))"
Range("L20").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J20="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J20))"
Range("L21").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J21="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J21))"
Range("L22").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J22="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J22))"
Range("L23").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J23="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J23))"
Range("L24").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J24="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J24))"
Range("L25").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J25="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J25))"
Range("L26").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J26="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J26))"
Range("L27").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J27="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J27))"
Range("L28").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J28="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J28))"
Range("L29").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J29="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J29))"
Range("L30").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J30="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J30))"
Range("L31").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J31="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J31))"
Range("L32").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J32="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J32))"
Range("L33").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J33="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J33))"
Range("L34").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J34="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J34))"
Range("L35").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J35="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J35))"
Range("L36").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J36="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J36))"
Range("L37").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J37="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J37))"
Range("L38").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J38="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J38))"
Range("L39").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J39="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J39))"
Range("L40").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J40="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J40))"
Range("L41").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J41="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J41))"
Range("L42").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J42="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J42))"
Range("L43").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J43="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J43))"
Range("L44").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J44="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J44))"
Range("L45").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J45="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J45))"
Range("L46").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J46="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J46))"
Range("L47").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J47="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J47))"
Range("L48").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J48="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J48))"
Range("L49").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J49="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J49))"
Range("L50").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J50="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J50))"

Range("N1").Value = "Customer:"
Range("N1").Font.Bold = True
Range("O1").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[Order Analysis.xlsm]Sheet1'!$C:$R,3,FALSE), )"
Range("O1").Font.Bold = True

Range("N2").Value = "Cust Ops:"
Range("N2").Font.Bold = True
Range("O2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[Order Analysis.xlsm]Sheet1'!$C:$R,16,FALSE), )"
Range("O2").Font.Bold = True

Range("N3").Value = "Order No:"
Range("N3").Font.Bold = True
Range("O3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=A2"
Range("O3").Font.Bold = True

Range("N4").Value = "Pallet Qty:"
Range("N4").Font.Bold = True
Range("O4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=B2"
Range("O4").Font.Bold = True

Range("N5").Value = "Picked Date:"
Range("N5").Font.Bold = True
Range("O5").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=H2"
Range("O5").Font.Bold = True
Range("O5").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

ActiveSheet.Columns("J:O").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Columns("J:O").AutoFit

Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

 Dim rng As Range, condition1 As FormatCondition

 Set rng = Range("J2:L10")
  
  With rng
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    Set condition1 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=And($K2 <>"""", $K2 > $L2)")
        Set condition2 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=And($L2 <>"""", $L2 > $K2)")
  End With
   With condition1
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
   End With
   With condition2
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
   End With

mynetwork.setdefaultprinter "\\DOFFUKFS01\Olivetti MF280 PS"
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 1
End With
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
ws.PrintOut
Next
wb.Close
FileName = Dir()
Loop
Kill "Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Despatches\*.csv"
mynetwork.setdefaultprinter "Microsoft Print to PDF"
    Dim FolderPath As String, count As Integer
    FolderPath = "Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Despatches"

    path = FolderPath & "\*.csv"

    FileName = Dir(path)

    Do While FileName <> ""
       count = count + 1
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Range("K5").Value = count
    'MsgBox count & " : files found in folder"
End Sub
```

Having pressed "F8" it looks like it just loops around this part of the code and doesn't know when to "Finish"?

```
    Range("J" & i + 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$K:$K, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A))+1, """"), ROW(A" & i & "))),"""")"
    Range("K" & i + 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$K:$K, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D))+1, """"), ROW(A" & i & "))),"""")"
Next i
```

Comment: *"Freezing"* in 99 % of the cases it occurs means the code is still running and has not finished yet. Check the value of `lastRow` if this is large the loop will take a long time to run. Also I recommend to turn off calculation before running the loop and turn it on after. So the sheet is not calculated in every step of the loop over and over again (which slows it down a lot).

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ thanks for your reply! I checked the value of lastRow and it is just 2 characters, the rest of the code takes seconds to run and then it freezes until I open task manager and "Kill it" I have left the "Freeze" running for 20minutes and still nothing :(

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? In the VBA editor put the cursor in the relevant sub and then press F8 repeatedly, it will execute the code line by line and highlight each line before it executes it. That way you can see which line is causing errors.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes Thanks for your reply, I have just tried this and it just loops around "Next i" and the 2 lines above it, I'm not sure if VBA knows when to "finish" this part of the code if that makes sense?

Comment: Is your "lastRow" giving correct result? Generally, I use the code "lastRow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row" to find the last row .

Comment: @JonnyUK what I meant is check the value of the *variable* `lastRow` (not the value in the cell). Try `Debug.Print lastRow` right after the variable was filled and check the output in the immediate window. • It looks like your loop is running to the very end of the sheet and this takes ages re-calculating the sheet each time. Turn off calculation too. We cannot help you if you don't try what we suggest.

Comment: @KVRamana Tried this and it stops the code from populating any fields in J or K completely, thank you for your time though

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Sorry I wasn't too sure what you meant, I added "Debug.Print lastRow" and this stops the code and highlights "Next i" in the VBA code? Also turned off calculation and this just makes the code freeze before it has populated fields J & K.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Ah, The code is indeed running down the entire sheet rather than stopping at the last row and that's why the code doesn't stop, any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: As KV Ramana said `lastRow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` will find the true last populated row in column J. After this row in column J only empty rows follow. Make sure you tell VBA which sheet the range is in `lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` If you use `Range` without telling which sheet you mean Excel will guess the sheet name and it might fail. Then you are trying to find the last row in the wrong sheet and the code fails completely. Therefore never use `Range` without providing a sheet name!

Comment: Perhaps rather than using a `For ... to lastrow` you could use `Do Until`? For example, `Do until Range("J", i+1).text = ""` would loop until the next cell was blank. (If you're using `Do` instead of `For`, replace `Next` at the end with `Loop`)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ,Thanks for adding your comments.@JonnyUK, most of your code will execute every time on different sheet if someone changes the active sheet and save the workbook. With your comment, "The code is indeed running down the entire sheet rather than stopping at the last row" it is clear that macro is considering last row as worksheets last row (last row number of excel sheet is 1048576 as per excel 2010). Just small correct to above code is you should also use full reference for Rows.Count. "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count".

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question (but I guess that plenty of people will agree on this remark):

You have plenty of lines like this:

```
Range("L43").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(J43="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J43))"
```

These can easily be replaced by this one-liner:

```
Range("L43").Formula = "=IF(J43="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J43))"
```

As a general rule: you don't need to select a cell to modify its value.
The mentioned simplification will make your code so much more readable.